# Ceiling light junction box multiple wire detection

Tags: light-fixture, junction-box

I have tried to change a ceiling light and am confused as to why there are so many cables jammed into the box and some of them are burnt. I need some advise as to what to do. I have attached the best image i can. Thanks in advance.

[image: image1]

Comment: The two obvious wires going to the lamp are the ones to focus on.  Don't dismantle any more, or you'll have a Big, Big Mess.

Comment: Harper. Thank you for the response. So to clarify, i should not worry about the burnt wires and just put my new lamp up?

Comment: I am just saying "don't dismantle any more" because that's urgent, and because an amazing number of people *do* dismantle lots of stuff and present us a photo of spaghetti to reconnect.  Don't fall in that trap.  We should still discuss your core question.

Comment: I am a novice and therefore do not want to be dismantling this mess as i have no experience. I just would like to verify if i can leave the wires 'as is' with the slightly burnt ones and just connect my new lamp to the wires the old lamp was connected to. Don't want a fire in my house !!

Comment: Fair enough.  Give it a sniff with the ol' nose.  If you smell burn marks they are pretty distinctive.  This could also be simple aging and discoloration of the wires.   I would expect to see overheat/burn damage on a single wire or two, *not* every wire equally.  Look around more and see if you can see anything like that.

Comment: Looks like its only on one and a close scan looks like it may be discoloration, no smell so going to leave everything alone and connect my new lamp. Appreciate the time and assistance.

Answer (score 1):

It appears, at one time, that the circuit took way too much heat.  I would not be comfortable leaving it like this, but I have done wiring for years.  When the breaker to the light is off, determine what else is on that circuit.  Then look at what these normally pull.  I am assuming this is a house 30+ years old.  I see 6 ground wires going into the electrical cap, but only 5 white neutrals going into that cap.  A question I have for you is why are you changing the light?  Was it a "honey, I don't like this light" or the light was not working correctly?  Do you have access to the wiring from above, like in the attic?  You can always just switch the light out and what you did by changing the light will not increase your chance of fire, but I would still check out what else is on that circuit.

Comment: The extra ground wire is going down the cable for the switch loop.

Comment: One ground wire is pigtailed to the metal box.  There should be 1 supply, 3 onward and 1 switch loop cable in the box.

Comment: Thank you for all the responses. And in response to Jim, yes to a 30+ year old home and unfortunately that is the attic ceiling, its been converted so theres no way of me getting above it without cutting a hole in the ceiling. The light was working before fine and the new one i installed is as well. I guess I will need to hire someone to look at it shortly.